# InflateException upon using PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I tried using the following library for sliding tabs:
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

I have installed the solution, extracted it, imported library in my Eclipse, built library project, taken library.jar files and add it as a library in my project.

Library project structure is as the following:

library --> src --> com.astuetz --> PagerSlidingTabStrip.java

Then i have added that code to my fragment XML file:

```html
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
         android:id="@+id/tabs"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="48dip"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_calendar" />
        
        <ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">

        
        </ViewPager>
```

When i'm trying to run, i got the following error:

```html
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.horizons.engiz/com.horizons.engiz.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #150: Error inflating class com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #150: Error inflating class com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at com.horizons.engiz.ui.FragTasksList.onCreateView(FragTasksList.java:59)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  ... 11 more
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  ... 23 more
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.astuetz.pagerslidingtabstrip.R$drawable
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip.<init>(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:98)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  at com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip.<init>(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:107)
05-14 15:11:36.938: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):  ... 26 more
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

You can post the complete error? I always use ViewPager out of PagerSlidingTabStrip, have you ever tried it?

**UPDATE**

Try like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Works for me, but i'm using android support v7 and "Android Studio IDE".

Comment: thanks for caring, full error has been added to the post